# How to call / execute Android BroadcastReceiver class on same file using AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have ActivityDashboard.java like this

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
    case R.id.tbnLogServiceToggle:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(isChecked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isChecked){
            StartAlarm();
        }else{
            StopAlarm();
        }
        break;
    }
}

public void StartAlarm(){
    try{
        _AlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        ittAlarm = new Intent(this, LoggingController.class);
        _PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, ittAlarm, 0);
        _AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, _PendingIntent);          Log.i("PAG ------->", "Starting Alarm");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("PAG ------->", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void StopAlarm(){
    if (_AlarmManager != null){
        _AlarmManager.cancel(_PendingIntent);
    }
}


class LoggingController extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            _CsvFileExporter.Export(new CsvFileExporter(context).GetExportFile(), stgBattery +  " - " + stgIOIO);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVING..." + stgBattery + " " + stgIOIO, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And after im running this, the LoggingController not executed even it written at Manifest as `<receiver>` what should i do ? i want running this Receiver every 1 hour every day ... and get data from variable inside the main class

Comment: @MikeM. yeah, but if i move it to own class i can't get data from that class

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

Intent ittAlarm = new Intent(this, LoggingController.class);

PendingIntent  _PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, ittAlarm ,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager _AlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

_AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  _PendingIntent );
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: still not executed :( is your BroadcastReceiver is in same file ?

Comment: have you reduce the time for seing it ? (one hour is not now...)

Comment: the only difference is I've put the class of BroadcastReceiver in another .java
Try this. (Have you put logcat to see where you pass ? )

Comment: so.. is that able to get data from ActivityDashboard.java ? if Broadcast Receiver is on different file ?

Comment: in my example, you change HOUR in SECOND ? (I think so but why not)

Comment: try and say if this works. If not I think you must use intent for passing data